# VSCode extension "SQL Tools" showing duplicate attributes in mysql database

Tags: visual-studio-code, sqltools

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ywvU.png)
I am using SQL tools extension in VScode and using sequelize library, managing the SQL database queries but recently i found a problem in the SQL tools database(extension in VScode) as it shows duplicate attributes as show in above figure. I am using Node version 20, sequelize version 6 but  it shows only single attributes in the table. I found it solution a lot in google but i did not found its solution?

Solve the duplication of attribute only in the table but i think table is correct because i did not give duplicate attribute in its model defination.

Comment: might be a case of https://github.com/mtxr/vscode-sqltools/issues/686.

Comment: I have seen all the cases but not work, although everything is fine, data is saved in the database but might be it an issue with the extension.